# Как сделать чтобы C++ код скомпилированный в VS 2019 работал во всех win платформах?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, компиляция

Написал неплохое приложение на C#, но чтобы запускать на других компах нужен был .net установленный. Перешел после на C++, все как надо написал, взял exe (release) перекинул на другой комп, запустил и вызывается ошибка  msvcp140.dll (тип компонент отсутствует) VS 2015. Как быть? Есть программы которые открываешь и без всего этого запускаются (exe). Почему мой не запускается? Как все это объединить?

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в неустановленном Microsoft Visual C++ 2015. Обычно у многих пользователей он стоит, но он не входит в состав Windows при установке. Ты на другом компе проверял те самые программы, которые запускаются без всего?

Comment: Сделал просто хело ворлд и запустил, опять требует. Значит скачать VS 2013 года и там что ле делать?